# Validate with Vuelidate on dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I have a form that adds fields dynamically on a click event. I am trying to have a minlength validation error show up when the field value is less than 9 digits after I change or blur it (That doesn't really matter). My problem here is that because the fields are created dynamically, and essentially the same v-model, it is applying the rule to all them. How can I make this work so that it only affects the one that the user is on? The screen loads with 10 of these and then they can add more. So while they're filling up the initial 10 fields, I don't want a validation to pop up after the 5th one on all the following fields because the 5th one failed.

Here is a simplified version of my code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button @click="onAddBarcodes">Add More</button>
        </div>
        <div v-for="(barcode, index) in barcodes" :key="index">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Starting Roll #:</label>
                    <input
                        name="startbarcoderoll"
                        maxlength="9"
                        v-model.trim="$v.barcode.barcodeStart.$model"
                        :id="barcode.id"
                        ref="bcentry"
                    />
                    <!-- max length message -->
                    <div v-if="!$v.barcode.barcodeStart.minLength">
                        <span
                            v-if="!$v.barcode.barcodeStart.minLength"
                        >App Barcode must be exactly {{$v.barcode.barcodeStart.$params.minLength.min}} characters.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button @click="onDeleteBarcodes(barcode.id)">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
const { minLength } = require("vuelidate/lib/validators");

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            barcodes: [],
            barcode: {
                barcodeStart: ""
            }
        };
    },
    validations: {
        barcode: {
            barcodeStart: {
                minLength: minLength(9)
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        scanBarcodeNumber(value) {
            this.barcode.barcodeStart = value;
            this.$v.barcode.barcodeStart.$touch();
        },

        onAddBarcodes() {
            const newBarcode = {
                id: Math.random() * Math.random() * 1000,
                barcodeStart: ""
            };
            this.barcodes.push(newBarcode);
        },
        onDeleteBarcodes(id) {
            this.barcodes = this.barcodes.filter(barcode => barcode.id !== id);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Let me show what's happening

EDIT: Vuelidate is installed and instantiated at the global Vue instance so I can use it in several places. That's why you don't see it in this particular code

[image: screenshot] [image: aftervalidation]

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic validations using `validations` function and add a `validation` for each `barcode`.

Use `` $v[`barcode-${index}`] `` instead of `$v.barcode` for each field:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button @click="onAddBarcodes">Add More</button>
        </div>
        <div v-for="(barcode, index) in barcodes" :key="index">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Starting Roll #:</label>
                    <input
                        name="startbarcoderoll"
                        maxlength="9"
                        v-model.trim="$v[`barcode-${index}`].barcodeStart.$model"
                        :id="barcode.id"
                        ref="bcentry"
                    />
                    <!-- max length message -->
                    <div v-if="!$v[`barcode-${index}`].barcodeStart.minLength">
                        <span
                            v-if="!$v[`barcode-${index}`].barcodeStart.minLength"
                        >App Barcode must be exactly {{$v[`barcode-${index}`].barcodeStart.$params.minLength.min}} characters.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button @click="onDeleteBarcodes(barcode.id)">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In your js part defined `validations` using `function` and define a barcode for earch field:

```js
export default {
  validations() {
    const rules = {};
    this.barcodes.forEach((item, index) => {
      rules[`barcode-${index}`] = {
        barcodeStart: {
          minLength: minLength(9),
        },
      };
    });
    return rules;
  },
};
```

I don't know if it's the efficient way, but it has to work as you wish.

Comment: So, it's emptying my v-model when I blur out. Or I should say, it's not binding. In other words, I can type in the fields and when I blur away, it removes what I typed

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use Vuelidate `$each`.

Look at the documentation here:
https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-collections-validation

Someone also made an article about it here:
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/09/30/vuejs-vuelidate-dynamic-form-example